# kusto percentile converstion

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have this search on KUSTO but I have a problem converting to percentile. I am able to convert to Gig/sec but not a percentile. when I did I only getting percentile for a total, not for each one. any help really appreciated.

```
AzureMetrics
             | where ResourceId contains "route"
             | where MetricName == "BitsInPerSecond"
             | where TimeGenerated > (now() - 60m) and TimeGenerated <= now()
             | summarize by Resource, inGigabitPersec=Maximum/100000000
             | summarize percentiles(inGigabitPersec, 100)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

percentiles() is an aggregation function (like count(), sum()), and if you would like to calculate it for each value of 'Resource'. The next example calculates P90, P95, and P100 per-each resource:

```
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceId contains "route"
| where MetricName == "BitsInPerSecond"
| where TimeGenerated > (now() - 60m) and TimeGenerated <= now()
| extend inGigabitPersec=Maximum/100000000
| summarize percentiles(inGigabitPersec, 90, 95, 100) by Resource
```